# Can I modify the Mac's default "next word" delineator to include an underscore?

Tags: macos, keyboard-shortcuts

For example, if I hold the option key and press the left arrow, the cursor jumps to the next space or special character. I use this a lot when naming files, for example, "description-date.ext". If I need to modify the date, I just hold down <kbd>option</kbd>+<kbd>shift</kbd>, press the left arrow, and type to replace "date". But if I name the file "description_date.ext" it doesn't count the underscore as a separator like the hyphen. Does anyone know how I can make it treat the underscore like the hyphen?

Comment: This question and its answers may be helpful: http://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/104143/how-do-i-change-which-characters-os-x-considers-a-word-for-arrow-key-skippi